# Handbrake was on while taking reverse

Tags: brakes, starting, handbrake, reverse-lights, tata

Bought a new tata nexon (automatic) and while trying to take car in reverse from a downward place handbrake was on by mistake, startes noticing burning rubber smell and smoke from bonnet. Immediately stopped the car. Is there any damage to the engine or other parts. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Damage to the engine?  Not at all.  Damage to the brake, perhaps.

My father once drove home from work with the handbrake fully engaged on a 1986 Peugeot.  When he arrived, there were clouds of smoke in the garage!  The brake worked fine for several years until he sold the car 40k miles later.  The engine also purred like a pussy cat.

God, how I miss that 505 Turbo!